# How do you use Mocha in create-react-app with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, enzyme, ts-node

I am using create-react-app (typescript) for creating react application but i wanted to use mocha + enzyme  instead of jest to test my React components.

before this i was using this test script

> "test" :"NODE_ENV=development mocha --watch-extensions tsx --watch --require ignore-styles --require babel-core/register ./src/*.test.tsx".

But mocha is not understanding tsx file which am importing.

**Test Script:**

> "test": "NODE_ENV=development mocha -r babel-core/register -r ts-node/register src/*.test.tsx".

**Error :**

```
TSError: Γ¿» Unable to compile TypeScript
src\ComponentTest.test.ts (7,34): Parameter 'obj' implicitly has an 'any' 
type. (7006)
src\ComponentTest.test.ts (7,237): Property 'default' does not exist on type 
'{}'. (2339)
 at getOutput (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:330:15)
at Object.compile (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:518:11)
at Module.m._compile (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:403:43)
at loader (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
at require.extensions.(anonymous function) (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:406:12)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:250:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:247:14)
at Mocha.run (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:576:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\AssetWise\BeConnect_AssetWiseConncet\AssetWiseCONNECT\src\Client\assetwiseconnect\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:637:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

**Test file:**

```
import * as expect from 'chai';
import * as React from 'react'; 
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
enzyme.configure({adapter : new Adapter()});

describe('simple test with mocha', () => {
    it('should pass' , () => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
        expect.expect(true).to.be.true;
    });
});

describe('testing react components', () => {
   const wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<App/>);
   expect.expect(wrapper.find('div')).to.have.length(1);  
 });
```

App component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
const logo = require('./logo.svg');

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <Sample/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this

```
import * as expect from 'chai';
describe('calculate', function() {
    let mainExpect = expect.expect;

    it('add', function() {
      let result = 5 + 2;
      mainExpect(result).equal(7);
    }); 
  });
```